# Can't use three dots to import in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, import

I know I can write this to import a component from another file in the same folder

```
import component from "./component.js"
```

And to import a component from another folder but in the same folder

```
import component from "../component/component.js"
```

But how can I import from another folder like this

```
import component from ".../anotherComponent/component.js"
```

It seems React can't import with 3 dots.

Comment: Are you looking for `../../anotherComponent/component.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use 2dots for two time

```
"../../anotherComponent/component.js"
```